# Configure AttributeRouting in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, attributerouting

I have an area `RetailersAssistance` and a controller-

```
namespace SkyTracker.Areas.RetailersAssistance.Controllers
{
  [RouteArea("ra")]
  public class LoginController : Controller
  {       
    [Route("foo")]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
}
```

I would like to reach `Test()` action method via `http://localhost:61899/ra/foo`.

I have configured RouteConfig.cs to allow Attribute Routing-

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This is my area registration code-

```
public class RetailersAssistanceAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "RetailersAssistance";
        }
    }


    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {

        context.MapRoute(
            "RetailersAssistance_default",
            "ra/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller="Login",  action = "Test", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "SkyTracker.Areas.RetailersAssistance.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

But the above url returns 404. What did I miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use  [context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()] in RegisterArea method like this :

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        context.MapRoute(
            "RetailersAssistance_default",
            "ra/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Test", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "SkyTracker.Areas.RetailersAssistance.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ActionName** instead of **Route** attribute.
Change

```
 [Route("foo")]
 public ActionResult Test()
 {
        return View();
  }
```

to

```
[ActionName("foo")]
public ActionResult Test()
{
   return View();
}
```